# Calculate new X,Y position based on angle center x,y is facing for a radar

Tags: c#, math

I have a radar in my game. Right now the radar works using a static X,Y graph that does not rotate based on how you are facing in my game.

I want the X, Y positions on the radar to rotate based on the direction you are facing. Monsters in the front of you will always appear at the top of the radar.

Right now, the radar is static and monsters north of you will always appear north on the radar.

Currently, I have math like this:

```
int x = (int)(x * Math.Cos(Math.PI * angle / 180) + y * Math.Sin(Math.PI * angle / 180));
int y = (int)(y * Math.Cos(Math.PI * angle / 180) - x * Math.Sin(Math.PI * angle / 180));
```

Then I add the center X and center Y to the integers above, but the graph is weird and only seems to work from 359~ degree angle. I have tried adding my center X and center Y before calculating it, but it is always off.

Other code I found online differentiated based on the degrees/angle.

```
if (angle >= 0 && angle <= 180)
{
x = (int)(x * Math.Cos(Math.PI * angle / 180) - y * Math.Sin(Math.PI * angle / 180));
y = (int)(x * Math.Sin(Math.PI * angle / 180) + y * Math.Cos(Math.PI * angle / 180));
}
else
{
x = (int)(x * Math.Cos(Math.PI * angle / 180) - y * Math.Sin(Math.PI * angle / 180));
y = (int)(x * Math.Sin(Math.PI * angle / 180) + y * Math.Cos(Math.PI * angle / 180));
}
```

What is the correct formula I need to take the Center X(cX), center Y(cY), the angle I am facing and the target X(tX), target Y(tY) to relocate the targets X & Y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the obvious answer is to use the same rotation code that rotates your point of view to rotate the radar coordinates, but I guess you rejected that for some reason.

all that example code is wrong `x` is being overwritten and then used to find the new value for `y`.  *That's never going to work.*

The basic basic rotation formula looks like this:

```
x2 = (int)(x * Math.Cos(Math.PI * angle / 180) - y * Math.Sin(Math.PI * angle / 180));
y2 = (int)(x * Math.Sin(Math.PI * angle / 180) + y * Math.Cos(Math.PI * angle / 180));
```

but if the payer moves away from 0,0 you'll want

```
x2 = (int)((x - player_x) * Math.Cos(Math.PI * angle / 180) - (y - player_y) * Math.Sin(Math.PI * angle / 180));
y2 = (int)((x - player_x) * Math.Sin(Math.PI * angle / 180) + (y - player_y) * Math.Cos(Math.PI * angle / 180));
```

that will keep 0,0 on the radar centred on the player

dpending on how your game measures angles you might need to swap the sign on the Sin terms .

Comment: It worked, I just removed subtracting the player position and adding it after your formula.